# How to delete rows from database while using Like in where clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have database table which has large number of rows. Now primary key of this table has special characters in a few of its rows. I want to delete them using this command.

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE symbol LIKE '%$%'
   OR symbol LIKE '%^%'
   OR symbol LIKE '%[%'
   OR symbol LIKE '%*%'
   OR symbol LIKE '%&%'
   OR symbol LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

But this query is taking a lot of time.

Is there any alternative way to make this query faster & more efficient? Please let me know if you need more details about my table or database. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will help a little bit:

```
WHERE symbol like '%[$^\[*&\%]%'
```

The default escape character is the backslash, so `ESCAPE '\'` is redundant.

However, because your query has to do a full table scan, this will help a bit but it will still be slow.